# Reading directory contents in variable in qshell

Tags: unix, ibm-midrange

I am trying to read directory contents in a variable using below script:

```
var1= ($(ls /user/test | grep -v '^d'))
for i in "${var1[@]}"                     
  do echo "$i"                            
done
```

Its not working for me its giving error:: 001-0049 Syntax error on line 1: token word not expected, expecting token ")"

I replaced variable substitution to :`var1= "$(ls /home/dmypgmr/pdfs | grep -v '^d')"` 
Still giving error:001-0019 Error found searching for command c and showing the listing on stdout and then an error message: 001-0048 Syntax error on line 2: variable substitution not valid.

Please suggest how i can accomplish that !

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to use arrays here. Just use the output of `ls`

```
ls -1 /user/test | grep -v '^d' | while read i
do
  echo "$i"                            
done
```

Comment: @abhinavsingh If this answer is still OK for you, please click the checkmark.